# Checkbox Group to Conditionally Appear Dependant on Another Cell's Value

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a list of people's names:
Katharine
Greg
Sue
Derek

If in the cell C3 the value of the cell is equal to "Blue Group", I'd like 4 blank checkboxes to appear in cell F3 with each name next to its own checkbox. This should be the same for all cells from C3 to C∞ - if the value is "Blue Group", the 4 checkboxes appear in the corresponding F column cell on the same row.

Then, once all 4 checkboxes have been ticked, I'd like the E column cell to be given the value "Yes", and otherwise be given the value "No".

I'm using Excel 2010. Is this possible? It's to allow each of the 4 people to confirm completion of an assigned activity

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Not much, I can get a single checkbox to appear dependant on the content of a single cell - nothing special. This one needs an Excel genius, and not even sure if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Creating checkboxes in advance and simply making them visible and invisible based on what has been entered in column C is certainly possible. Then whenever a checkbox value is changed, the checkbox change event can check the rest of the checkboxes to see if they've all been filled in or not and make the proper changes from there. This would work if you have a finite and preset number of rows instead of going to infinity like you suggested.

Creating the checkboxes dynamically from the code is an interesting challenge, I'm not sure if it's possible or not. If it has to be this way I'd suggest doing it a different way. Maybe instead have one column per person and put a dropdown list where they select the status. Dropdown lists can be created in the four cells in question when "Blue Group" has been entered for a particular row. The worksheet change event can then be used to check if all the cells have been filled in and take it from there.

Either way it's a bit of work and you probably won't get any full code for it from stackoverflow.